# What is Slickflow? How to use it in Dot Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm new to Slickflow. What is the use of Slickflow in Dot net core and how to use it? Is it an API or MVC Project or something other?

Edit:-

How can I implement Slickflow in my project? Give an example like see Users flow or anything you want. I'm considering which classes and how to do make a diagram?

Comment: I'm read document. But I don't get it @FranzGleichmann

Comment: Hard to know what your exact problem is, consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61767600/edit) and adding a more concrete problem. Otherwise this question could be considered "too broad" and closed. The help page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) could help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about this [SlickFlow](http://www.slickflow.com/). It looks like a .NET, .NET CORE Open Source Workflow Engine with this [GitHub](https://github.com/besley/Slickflow) repo. Here is their [Quick Start Tutorial](https://github.com/besley/Slickflow/wiki/Slickflow-Quick-Start-Tutorial) as well as some [SlickFlow Application Code Example](https://github.com/besley/Slickflow/wiki/Slickflow-Application-Code-Example) with complete C# code.

Comment: I can't really explain what a workflow engine is better than Wikipedia. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine

Comment: I want to know how to implement this in my project.

Comment: @NitikaChopra, there are some example projects in slickflow community edtion, you can download source code from github. http://github.com/besley/slickflow

Answer (score 0):

There are two articles from code project:

[Slickflow NETCore Open Source Workflow Engine](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5246528/Slickflow-NET-Core-Open-Source-Workflow-Engine)

[Slickflow Coding Graphic Model User Manual](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5252483/Slickflow-Coding-Graphic-Model-User-Manual)

I am one contributor from slickflow team, if someone has any questions, we can do any help here. Thanks